# Prettier showing error despite having formatted the file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Prettier is set up within the User settings in VSCode. The path to it is provided being the global installation. The path to the config is also provided, being the .prettierrc file within the repo.

There's a ton of errors being shown by prettier as seen in this picture:
[image]
[image]

If I hit save (because format on save is on), it will not format anything.

If I hover over the error and click 'fix all prettier issues', it will format it. But then give me the exact same error.

Can't seem to be able to get out of this hole.

Comment: I could be due to VS Code prettier extension not using your prettier config file but a global one, and the formatter using the correct file

Comment: try this `npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier` and then inside your  working directory `npx prettier --write .` instead!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had 2 prettier VS extensions enabled at the same time which were messing with each other.